# Apache activate issue on Mac Sierra

Tags: apache

I've followed instruction on how to activate Apache on my Mac prior to upgrading to Sierra. I got the "It Works" page after entering localhost in the address field, yet after I upgraded to Sierra, I got the "This site cannot be reached" page.

All of my (Google) searches say to to deactivate Apache with this:
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

but, when I use that, this is returned: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

I have tried: sudo achapectl stop,
but receive: sudo: achapectl: command not found

Can someone help!?

Comment: This seems more relevant for [apple.se] than [so]

Comment: Did you try reversing the command per the email below? You will get the message if you unload two times.

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```